# Address bar / URL bar not shrinking in mobile safari on scrolling

Tags: css, mobile-safari, address-bar

I am building a website using React (16.8.6) but it does not collapse/shrink the url bar in mobile safari as the user starts scrolling unlike on other websites

The CSS for the wrapper divs looks as follows:

```js
<ContentContainer>
    <ScrollContainer>
        {...otherComponentsHere}
    <ScrollContainer/>
<ContentContainer/>
```

```css
const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100%; /*allows both columns to span the full height of the browser window*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const ScrollContainer = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
`;
```

App.css looks as follows:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'Courier New', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#app {
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; /*makes the body non-scrollable*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what's wrong in this CSS which is preventing safari url bar to collapse as the user scrolls. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To collapse/shrink the url bar in mobile safari, you have to have your `body` to overflow the viewport, which is not the case here: you have `body` non-scrollable, and your `ContentContainer` is whole in the viewport.

To test this, just create a new page with no CSS, and put into `body` enough content to make the page scrollable.

Comment: I tried removing `overflow: hidden` but it still doesn't solve the issue. I can scroll smoothly but the url bar still doesn't shrink

Comment: @PoojaChawla, yes, probably you're scrolling content inside scrollable `ContentContainer` which is whole in the viewport, therefore `body` is still not scrolling? Sorry if it's confusing, English is not my first language.